# Vim, MacVim, and Unicode

Tags: macvim

Unicode characters appear in regular old vim in the terminal (iTerm), but not MacVim. Is there a way to get MacVim to handle Unicode characters appropriately. If it helps, I installed them using homebrew.

I grabbed these lines from the [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode):

```
if has("multi_byte")
  if &termencoding == ""
    let &termencoding = &encoding
  endif
  set encoding=utf-8
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
  "setglobal bomb
  set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif
```

Comment: What exactly is MacVim doing wrong?  Unicode works fine on my install in both GUI and Terminal (mvim -m) mode.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean that Unicode characters don't render correctly try disable the "Use Core Text renderer" option in the "Preferences… → Advanced" menu and restart MacVim. ([source 1](https://twitter.com/itg/status/503983241670696961), [source 2](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.mac/9706))

I have a similar problem, in which emoji charachters are rendered to big, but as of yet I don't know how to fix it.